# I'm trying to center my page for all three of the main browsers but it only works for Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to center my webpage but it doesn't seem to be working. I can get it to work for Internet Explorer but only when I'm accessing it while it's stored on a server. When it's stored locally, it isn't centered. In any case, it's never centered in Firefox or Chrome. Could someone take a look at my code and see if they have any solutions?

Sorry if the code is messy. Any cleanup tips would be appreciated as well :)
I used Dreamweaver CC.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Text</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-image: url(images/image.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat;
 font-family: "French Script MT";
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
 color: #B9AB90;
}

.Memories {
        font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
        font-size: 18pt;
        color: #360D11;
}
.Text {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #7A2500;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
}

.Bottom {
 font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 color: #000000;
}
.SessionMain {
 color: #170C03;
 font-family: special-elite;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 24pt;
}
.SessionHead {
 color: #4C3223;
 font-family: ewert;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 40pt;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}
</style>
<meta name="keywords" content="test, test2" />
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.--><script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/spicy-rice:n4:default;special-elite:n4:default;ewert:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body background="image.png">
<p><a name="Top" id="Top"></a></p>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="70">&nbsp;</td> <!-- Width here will set how far from the left      the page is -->
      <td><div align="center">
        <table width="1030" border="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td height="87"><div align="center">
        <table width="629" height="83" border="5" bordercolor="#784321" bordercolordark="#7A2401" bgcolor="#FFE6A8">
          <tr>
            <td width="606" height="69"><div align="center" style="font-size: 46px; color: #4C3223;"><strong>Text</strong></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  
</div>


<div align="center">
  
  
</div>
<p>
  
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="73">&nbsp;</td>
      <
      <td width="629" height="87"><div align="center">
        <table width="1020" height="83" border="5" bordercolor="#784321" bordercolordark="#7A2401" bgcolor="#FFE6A8">
          <tr>
            <td width="606" height="69"><div align="center" class="SessionHead" style="font-size: 46px; color: #4C3223;">Text</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
        <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</p>
<table width="100%" border="4" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="1364">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div align="center">
  <table height="95" width="1016" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="15" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#2E190B">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="986" height="18" bgcolor="#2E190B">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="15" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#2E190B">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="77" bgcolor="#DFB47F"><table width="97%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="98%"><p class="Bottom"><a href="#Top"><a href="#Top">Back To Top</a></p>
                <p class="Bottom">Last Updated: Sunday, January 4, 2015 10:42 AM</p></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


      </body>

</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Validate your HTML first - you get a ton of errors if you attempt to validate that.

Comment: Developers havent laid out websites with `tables` since the late 90s/early 2000's. You need to remove all of those and re-do this with `div`s

Comment: @jmore009 Quite a lot of websites these days are laid out using some tables.

Comment: new ones? you would have to find me some, cause i strongly disagree with that - tables are for tabular-data not for building the frame of your website

Comment: @patricksweeney Sorry, I'm new at this, what does it mean to validate my HTML?

Comment: Steer well clear of using tables for layout. Makes web dev ***so*** much harder.

Comment: @user3254612: You're HTML isn't 'correct'. It's 'invalid'/'incorrect'.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/ It means to make sure your HTML is correct. And as others have said, don't use tables for layout. It's archaic and not easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `body` style to the following (Remove `display: table-cell` and add `width` and `margin` properties):

```
body {
    background-image: url(images/image.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    font-family: "French Script MT";
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    color: #B9AB90;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Code Snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Text</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-image: url(images/image.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat;
 font-family: "French Script MT";
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
 color: #B9AB90;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.Memories {
        font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
        font-size: 18pt;
        color: #360D11;
}
.Text {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #7A2500;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
}

.Bottom {
 font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 color: #000000;
}
.SessionMain {
 color: #170C03;
 font-family: special-elite;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 24pt;
}
.SessionHead {
 color: #4C3223;
 font-family: ewert;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 40pt;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}
</style>
<meta name="keywords" content="test, test2" />
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.--><script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/spicy-rice:n4:default;special-elite:n4:default;ewert:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body background="image.png">
<p><a name="Top" id="Top"></a></p>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="70">&nbsp;</td> <!-- Width here will set how far from the left      the page is -->
      <td><div align="center">
        <table width="1030" border="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td height="87"><div align="center">
        <table width="629" height="83" border="5" bordercolor="#784321" bordercolordark="#7A2401" bgcolor="#FFE6A8">
          <tr>
            <td width="606" height="69"><div align="center" style="font-size: 46px; color: #4C3223;"><strong>Text</strong></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  
</div>


<div align="center">
  
  
</div>
<p>
  
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="73">&nbsp;</td>
      <
      <td width="629" height="87"><div align="center">
        <table width="1020" height="83" border="5" bordercolor="#784321" bordercolordark="#7A2401" bgcolor="#FFE6A8">
          <tr>
            <td width="606" height="69"><div align="center" class="SessionHead" style="font-size: 46px; color: #4C3223;">Text</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
        <div align="center"></div></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</p>
<table width="100%" border="4" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="1364">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div align="center">
  <table height="95" width="1016" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="15" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#2E190B">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="986" height="18" bgcolor="#2E190B">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="15" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#2E190B">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="77" bgcolor="#DFB47F"><table width="97%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="98%"><p class="Bottom"><a href="#Top"><a href="#Top">Back To Top</a></p>
                <p class="Bottom">Last Updated: Sunday, January 4, 2015 10:42 AM</p></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


      </body>

</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly! How do you mark the question as resolved?

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0pj8p8jx/3/)**

Remove `display: table-cell` from body

add new class inside `body` closing before `</body>`

```
.center-all {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1030px;
}
```

**[Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/)**

> This validator examines markup for validity of Web documents in HTML,
>   XHTML etc

Note that you have so many syntax errors like `</table>` is not closing, `</body>` is closing inside table. You need to validate your HTML to fix HTML issues. So many compatibility errors are due to invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

"Sorry if the code is messy." Indeed, like patricksweeney said start to clean your code :

- your "body" balise end in the middle of nowhere !!!
- you use the "table" balise everywhere for no reason
- etc

I think the best thing to do right now is to start a new tuto and learn html/css step by step...

(PS : delete the "display: table-cell;" in body css to center the page.)